# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::helper() in /home/primasource/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 308

Tags: magento

I am getting the error on my home page. i don't what the issue is .. request support on the same. tried all steps . searching for an answer.atal error: Call to undefined method Mage::helper() in /home/primasource/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 308

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile it again,

go to your admin painel > System menu -> Tools > Compiler > Run Process of compilation or Disable

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're dealing with a significantly hacked system -- in a standard system the static `Mage::helper` method is defined in

```
#File: app/Mage.php
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

If your system can't find this, it means someone has edited your core `app/Mage.php` to remove this method, someone has removed the `Mage` class, or someone has changed your system to use a different `Mage` class.  Start debugging there, and good luck!